# One to one function but not surjective

Tags: calculus, functions

Give an example of a function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, which is one to one but not surjective.
 I get the answer $f(x)= x^2$ but i am not sure if this is not onto! i am still confusing about surjective functions.

Comment: Write down what you have been told "onto" means. Then see if that function matches the definition.

Comment: I suspect this was an exercise intended to teach the distinction between $1-1$ and onto.  Many authors use the phrase *one-to-one* to mean that a function is both $1-1$ and onto.  Check your textbook (or lecture notes) for the precise definition being used in your class.

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2}$

Comment: You give a bijection... try some variation of your function (tip: plot a graph)

Comment: Surjective means that all the value of the "target" set $[0,1]$ come from some $x\in[0,1]$. If you consider
$$y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$$ for instance, the set of the images of the function is $[0,1/2]$ and all the values in $[1/2,1]$ have no counter image, so the function is $1-1$ (injective) but not onto (surjective)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding examples of functions doing things is a great way to test your understanding. Often, there are many examples of functions satisfying specified conditions, so you can't start 'guessing'.

For this problem, you said you are confused about surjectivity. Here is a 'real world' problem for you to work on. You are looking for a function that does NOT MAP ONTO $[0,1]$. So it is up to you to simply pick a point that is 'not hit'. How about $1$? If your function has to 'keep its distance' from $1$, try coming up with a function

$\tag ? f: [0,1] \to [0, \frac{1}{2}]$

such that it maps

$\tag 0 0 \mapsto 0$
$\tag 1 1 \mapsto \frac{1}{2}$

Now your $x^2$ function was a good start since it injective on $[0,1]$, but now you have to find a way to 'adjust it' so that both (0) and (1) hold true. A good idea is to get out some graph paper so you can 'see' what is going on.

When you come up with an answer, recheck your work and understanding of the definitions of injectivity and surjectivty.

Answer (score 0):

Consider$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}\qquad x\in[0,1]$$Do you see why $f$ is injective but not surjective?